# Trying to enable "perform maven release" to free style project

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I am trying to extend the m2release plugin to free style project. So far I am able to get the "maven release build" option for the Build environment in the configuration of a free style project. But when I select this option for the free style project the "Perform maven release" button is not popping up in the left side menu.

My concern is am I trying something which is not feasible. I mean asking M2release-plugin to perform release for free style project.

If this is feasible, which class of the plugin should I look in to get the "perform maven release" enabled for free style project? I am currently trying to modify the M2ReleaseBuildWrapper class and M2ReleaseAction class.